# cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, android

Не знаю в чём ошибка сижу 2ой час

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Worik\app\src\main\java\kirill\golub\worik\activity\ScoreCardActivity.java:160: error: method setDescription in class Chart<T> cannot be applied to given types;
        mPieChart.setDescription();
                 ^
  required: Description
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends ChartData<? extends IDataSet<? extends Entry>> declared in class Chart
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Worik\app\src\main\java\kirill\golub\worik\activity\ScoreCardActivity.java:167: error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Entry> cannot be converted to List<PieEntry>
        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yvalues, AppConstants.EMPTY_STRING);
                                            ^
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Worik\app\src\main\java\kirill\golub\worik\activity\ScoreCardActivity.java:174: error: no suitable constructor found for PieData(ArrayList<String>,PieDataSet)
        PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);
                       ^
    constructor PieData.PieData() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor PieData.PieData(IPieDataSet) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Worik\app\src\main\java\kirill\golub\worik\activity\ScoreCardActivity.java:183: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
4 errors
```

Строки с ошибкой:

```
public void showPieChart() {
        mPieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.piechart);
        mPieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
        mPieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
        mPieChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(AppConstants.TRANSPARENT_CIRCLE_RADIUS);
        mPieChart.setHoleRadius(AppConstants.TRANSPARENT_CIRCLE_RADIUS);
        mPieChart.setDescription(getString(R.string.score_card));
        mPieChart.animateXY(AppConstants.ANIMATION_VALUE, AppConstants.ANIMATION_VALUE);

        ArrayList<Entry> yvalues = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        yvalues.add(new Entry(mScore, AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY_ZERO_INDEX));
        yvalues.add(new Entry(mWrongAns, AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY_SECOND_INDEX));
        yvalues.add(new Entry(mSkip, AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY_FIRST_INDEX));
        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yvalues, AppConstants.EMPTY_STRING);
        dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);

        ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
        xVals.add(getString(R.string.score));
        xVals.add(getString(R.string.wrong));
        xVals.add(getString(R.string.skipped));
        PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);

        // In percentage Term
        data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
        mPieChart.setData(data);


    }
```

Comment: в ошибке написано: `mPieChart.setDescription()` хочет аргументов

Comment: mPieChart.setDescription(getString(R.string.score_card)); Аргументы есть

Comment: значит всё в порядке. Правда пишет, что аргументы не те. Вы точно `String` принимаете?

Comment: и вот: `error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Entry> cannot be converted to List<PieEntry>` и тут `no suitable constructor found for PieData(ArrayList<String>,PieDataSet)`. Всё написано, что не так

Comment: Это я понял, но не знаю что сделать с этим

Comment: Судя по всему вы принимаете один тип, а передаете другой. Покажите, как вы принимаете аргументы в функциях, которые вызываете в строках 160, 167 и 174...

Comment: @TheSkyNed, очень похоже, что вы пытаетесь какой-то старый код "натянуть" на более новую версию библиотеки. Прочтите документацию, посмотрите актуальные примеры и перепишите заново.